# Взятие программно отклика исполняемой среды на команду в оную

Tags: g++, c++, bash, linux

Знаю как передать из программы команду в исполняемую среду
     < unistd.h >
     system("");
пример для линуха. 
**Вопрос: как взять в программу, ответ на команду средой?**
пример: передаю команду (в bash) pwd, которая выводит адрес текущей директории, как можно взять его например в строку?
Или еще: посылаю команду ping, как ее остановить? передача символа ^C не помагает, вернее он передается, когда я уже вручную останавливаю пингование.

Comment: popen? (в смысле man 3 popen)

Comment: а можно по подробнее? ну там: библиотака ее, пример использования самый примитивный или хотя бы какие параметры у нее и как обозначается  
заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример из [link text](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=popen&category=3&russian=4#lbAH) что-ли...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
   char *cmd = "/usr/bin/ls *.c";
   char buf[BUFSIZ];
   FILE *ptr;

   if ((ptr = popen(cmd, "r")) != NULL) {
           while (fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, ptr) != NULL)
                   (void) printf("%s", buf);
           (void) pclose(ptr);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Или нужны примеры использования других вызовов: pipe, fork, exec, wait?

Comment: спасибо конечно, но пример бы я и сам смог найти, мне бы вот пару коментов относительно параметров

Comment: Извините, не понимаю... Первый параметр - команда для /bin/sh. (Результат /bin/sh -c команда). Второй - режим: r - для чтения через трубу из дочернего процесса, w - для записи (передачи в дочерний процесс). Для pwd - заменяете /usr/bin/ls *.C в примере на pwd - и всё. Для ping'а - надо смотреть, что вы хотите. Если Вы выдадите pclose, то дочерний процесс помрёт, однако.